# Join where does not equal

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two queries I have created in Access and I'm a step away from arriving at the data I need. I need to subset in some way.

Table1 and Table2 (Actually query1 and query2). They both have 3 fields: Email, Matcher and List.

I need to get all the results from Table2 where Email does not exist in Table1.

I found some posts about using an outer join and where null clause. I could not get it to work though. Didn't post what I tried here in case I was off course.

Comment: Where email doesn't exist with what criteria? When `table1.matcher = table2.matcher and table1.list = table2.list and table1.email is null`? Or just joining on matcher? You still have to join on some criteria or it will just do a cartesian product. Can you provide some example data with the desired output and your sql attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on t2.email = t1.email
where t1.email is null
```

Comment: Thanks that looks like I got it now

Comment: Just curious, was trying to run this query without the t1 and t2 notation, instead keeping the full names of the tables but Access keeps telling me I have a syntax error when I do that. Is this query only possible using shortened table names t1, t2 as opposed to table1, table2 throughout?

Comment: You don't need the alias names. The query then is: `select table2.*
from table2
left join table1 on table2.email = table1.email
where table1.email is null`

Comment: That's what I thought but this keeps giving me a syntax error for the join statement after the ON word:
SELECT 004_PublishingUnion.*
FROM 004_PublishingUnion LEFT JOIN 007_MatchedOnEmail ON 004_PublishingUnion.Email = 007_MatchedOnEmail.Email
WHERE 007_MatchedOnEmail.Email IS NULL;
Does anything stand out?

Comment: Actually I can't see why this should not work. But I don't have Access here to test. If it keeps not working you can ask another question about it with the complete error message.

Comment: Hm. Well thanks allt he same I suspect that it's Access' SQL playing funny games

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM table1 t1 
                   WHERE t1.email = t2.email
                 )
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I already tried juergen's answer by the time I read this.

Comment: @Doug Firr : Yep, the thing is, that I don't really know what answer has a better performance in _MS Access_, that is why I've posted this one with `NOT EXISTS` too.